# Derivative of a map at a point.

Tags: real-analysis

For V = $(V_{1},V{2})$ $\in$ $R^2$ and $W = (W_{1}, W_{2})$ $\in$ $R^2$, consider the determinant map $det: R^2 \longrightarrow R^2$ defined by $ det(V,W) =V_{1}W_{2}-W_{1}V_{2}$. Then what is the derivative of the determinant map at (V,W) $\in R^2$ evaluated on (H,K)  $\in R^2$?
My attempt:- Since there are four variables in the map derivative of the function is nothing but $\nabla(f)$. But this will give me a $4*1$ column vector. And the book gave $det(V,H)+ det(K,W)$. Can someone please help?

Comment: What is $\nabla(f)$? $f$ isn't even defined! Recall that the derivative of a function $F : \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^m$ at a point $v \in \mathbb R^n$ is a *linear map* $DF(v) : \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^m$, so it can be evaluated at points in $\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: By f what I meant was the determinant map